# grub-efi-arm64-signed : Depends: grub-efi-arm64 (= 2.06-2ubuntu7) but 2.06-2ubuntu10 is to be installed

Tags: package-management

```
# apt clean

# apt update
Hit:1 http://ca-central-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://ca-central-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://ca-central-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
24 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 grub-efi-arm64-signed : Depends: grub-efi-arm64 (= 2.06-2ubuntu7) but 2.06-2ubuntu10 is to be installed
E: Broken packages

# apt show -a grub-efi-arm64 2>/dev/null | grep -P "Version:|APT-Sources:"
Version: 2.06-2ubuntu10
APT-Sources: http://ca-central-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/main arm64 Packages
Version: 2.06-2ubuntu7
APT-Sources: http://ca-central-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main arm64 Packages

# curl -s "http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy/main/binary-arm64/Packages.gz" | zgrep -B 13 "Depends: grub-efi-arm64" | grep -P "Package:|Depends:"
Package: grub-efi-arm64-dbg
Depends: grub-efi-arm64-bin (= 2.06-2ubuntu7)
Package: grub-efi-arm64-signed
Depends: grub-efi-arm64 (= 2.06-2ubuntu7)

# curl -s "http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages.gz" | zgrep -B 13 "Depends: grub-efi-arm64" | grep -P "Package:|Depends:"
Package: grub-efi-arm64-dbg
Depends: grub-efi-arm64-bin (= 2.06-2ubuntu10)
Package: grub-efi-arm64-signed
Depends: grub-efi-arm64 (= 2.06-2ubuntu10)
```

That's an Ubuntu bug right?

Comment: I think jammy-security is missing on your system.

Comment: FYI, as of 10/30/2022, the ...10 package is 25% on a phased upgrade according to apt-cache policy grub-efi-amd64-signed.

Comment: @ubfan1 yes Ubuntu fixed it a few days after it was reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is a critical bug impacting arm64 servers;

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2-signed/+bug/1990684

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo apt install apt --upgrade
```

This fixed the issue for me on oracle cloud's arm servers using ubuntu 22.04

Comment: yes Ubuntu fixed it a few days after it was reported.

Comment: thank you, it fixed my problem also.

Comment: excellent my dear sir!

Answer (score 0):

```
grub-efi-arm64-signed : Depends: grub-efi-arm64 (= 2.06-2ubuntu7) but 2.06-2ubuntu10 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

If you have the above error, then run the command

```
sudo apt install apt
```